# ActionMode with same theme as Toolbar in Android

Tags: java, android, action-menu

In Android, is there any way to give an ActionMode the same appearance as the normal Toolbar? Currently my ActionMode looks different to the Toolbar in that the background is slightly brighter (at least using `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`), the MenuItems are fully black/white (depending on the theme) instead of `colorControlNormal` (which I set them to) and most annoyingly, there is an underline under the ActionMode that I can't seem to get rid of. Instead, I'm trying to make the ActionMode indistinguishable from the Toolbar.

The Toolbar (also what the ActionMode is meant to look like):
[image: Toolbar]

What the ActionMode currently looks like:
[image: ActionMode]

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For changing the background color of `ActionMode` & Remove the bottom line. You can use `actionModeStyle` where you can set `background` to your desired color.
2. For changing the icon color you can set `colorControlNormal` inside the `actionBarTheme`.

So your theme would look like this:

```
<style name="Theme.AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <!--add this-->
        <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/ActionModeStyle</item>
        <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>

    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        //replace with your own desired color
        <item name="colorControlNormal">#a00</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionModeStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">
        //replace with your own desired color
        <item name="background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/ActionModeTitleTextStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionModeTitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionMode.Title">
        //replace with your own desired color
        <item name="android:textColor">#a00</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me a lot! Works perfectly!